# Why is my font attribute causing an error that deletes parts of my code and applying to the unintended parts?

Tags: html, fonts, size

SOLVED: answer is actually in Mio Mio's comment
I'm super new to coding/programming and have no background in any maths/computing/sciences at all. Have hit a small roadblock in my online learning, I'm sure anyone on here would take 5 seconds to see the problem.

So my whole code went fine like this:

```
<doctype! html>
<html>
<head>
<h1>Blah</h1>

<h3>blah, blah, blah</h3>

<button>blah</button> <button>blah</button> 

<hr>

<h2>Review of blah</h2>

<img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" alt="picture of elephant" width="270" height="300">

<p>blah blah blah.</p>

<hr>
```

Then I replaced the h1 heading with

```
<h1 style="font-size:60px;">Blah</h1>
```

And it deleted everything before the 1st paragraph and turned all the text from the first paragraph until the hr tag size 60 font (with or without the hr tag, the result is the same).

I have NFC why this has happened because when trying it on the editor as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<h2>The style Attribute</h2>
<p>The style attribute is used to specify the styling of an element, like color:</p>

<h1 style="font-size:60px;">This is a heading.</h1>

<p>what am I doing right here</p>

</head>
</html>
```

, it works as intended.

As far as my guesses go, I've closed the h1 tag, so the style attribute shouldn't be applying to anything apart from the h1 heading.

Any help is appreciated, in explaining why this has happened, and how to avoid in future. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The problem seems to be when I copy and paste this into the w3 editor from notepad. style="font-size:60px;” I've tried typing manually, and then typing manually again into notepad, and copy pasting that, which doesn't lead to the aforementioned error. I don't see any differences so am unsure why it even registers them as different.

EDIT: It was the quote marks, for those curious! See earlier edit for the actual text that caused the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting like you said, it looks fine to me, as in the following link.
https://jsfiddle.net/81qzL4ft/

Maybe the problem is where you are running, try to use the latest google chrome.

```
<doctype! html>
<html>
<head>
<h1 style="font-size:60px;">Blah</h1>

<h3>blah, blah, blah</h3>

<button>blah</button> <button>blah</button> 

<hr>

<h2>Review of blah</h2>

<img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" alt="picture of elephant" width="270" height="300">

<p>blah blah blah.</p>

<hr>
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming! Should've tried another link I guess. Must just be the "w3 try it editor' I'm using that has its own bugs or issues. Just tried it again on w3, and it seems to have the same error only when I've copied and pasted this from notepad: 
style="font-size:60px;” but not when typing in manually. So strange. It has a mind of its own it seems.

Comment: Ohh, I see!
If you pay attention to your comment, you can see that the end quote is different from the starting quote, that's because the letters might look the same, but have different encoding value, like: 1 and １(The second one is written using the japanese keyboard).

Comment: I think you've cracked the code ;) hahaha. I didn't realise at all. Strangely, I'm pretty sure I hit the same button on my laptop for that quote, but it reformatted as a Jap keyboard quote mark. I'll keep my eyes peeled for that same thing in future.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to reproduce the effects you describe (might be a difference of browsers - I tried out Firefox and Chrome), but I think a good first step would be to ensure that your HTML is correct:

- The document type should be `<!DOCTYPE html>` and not `<doctype! html>`
- Contents of the `<head>` element should be stuff such as a page title, CSS and script files to include, and the like. You've put the entire body of your page into `<head>`, which is incorrect.
- Put the content of your page into a `<body>` element, instead.
- All HTML elements should be closed. For example, a `<h1>` should have a matching `</h1>`. For empty elements such as `<br>`, you should either do `<br></br>` or `<br/>`.

I've rewritten your problematic example here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My first HTML page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Blah</h1>

<h3>blah, blah, blah</h3>

<button>blah</button> <button>blah</button> 

<hr>

<h2>Review of blah</h2>

<img src="https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg" alt="picture of elephant" width="270" height="300" />

<p>blah blah blah.</p>

<hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

Browsers try to figure out "what you meant" if HTML code isn't 100% correct, but sticking to the standards gets you a long way in making sure a page renders correctly and in the same way across browsers.

If you're unsure of what may be causing issues in your code, you can also try running it through the W3C's HTML validator: https://validator.w3.org/ . It's quite strict (and might be hard to understand for a beginner), but does a good job of highlighting concrete issues with your code.

Comment: Ahh, seems its what Mio Mio above said. Different quote marks, which I may not have exactly replicated in the question. One is a normal " the other, a japanese keyboard "- not sure why this occured when I'm on a laptop hitting the same key for " haha. Thanks for your critique though, I'll keep those in mind. A stricter method from beginning is kind of what I'm after. 95 errors! Holy moly..